# How to add xml attributes to temp table fields in Progress

Tags: xml, openedge

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttTest 
FIELD One   AS CHARACTER
FIELD Two   AS CHARACTER
FIELD Three AS CHARACTER
.
```

I want to have field 'Two' have an attribute 'name' and then a value.

So it ends up like this...

```html
   <ttTest>
      <One>bla</One>
      <Two name="somethingLifeChanging">blabla</Two>
      <Three>blablabla</Three>
   </ttTest>
```

Any ideas how I can go about achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a DataSet you can nearly get there (if you are not concerned about the order of the elements):

```
define temp-table ttTest
  field parent  as recid xml-node-type "hidden"
  field One     as char
  field Three   as char
  .

define temp-table ttTestTwo serialize-name "Two"
  field parent  as recid xml-node-type "hidden"
  field name    as char xml-node-type "attribute"
  field Two     as char xml-node-type "text"
  .  

define dataset ds serialize-hidden 
  for ttTest,ttTestTwo
  data-relation for ttTest,ttTestTwo relation-fields( parent, parent ) nested foreign-key-hidden.  

create ttTest.
assign
   ttTest.parent    = recid(tttest)
   ttTest.One       = "bla"
   ttTest.Three     = "blablabla"
   .
create ttTestTwo.
assign
   ttTestTwo.parent = recid( ttTest )
   ttTestTwo.name   = "something"
   ttTestTwo.Two    = "blabla"
   .      

def var lcc as longchar.

dataset ds:handle:write-xml( "longchar", lcc, true ).

message string(lcc ) view-as alert-box.
```

The output is then:

```
---------------------------
Message
---------------------------
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ttTest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <One>bla</One>
  <Three>blablabla</Three>
  <Two name="something">blabla</Two>
</ttTest>
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write the temp-table XML into an X-DOCUMENT and manipulate the XML there.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thank you very much.